# Pyspark: Issues With Inserting Into a table in Hive using Zeppelin Notebook

Tags: python, hive, pyspark

NOTE: This is being written in a Zeppelin Notebook.

I've been trying to copy the contents of a source table, turn NULLS to 0's and insert that into a target table.  However, I've been running into the error:

```
AnalysisException: u'\nUnsupported language features in query: INSERT INTO TABLE..
```

When reading online, it would appear that Spark doesn't support INSERT INTO, however, I've been reading that you can use a dataframe and append it to the table. Here's my original code:

```
%pyspark
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM test_target")

dfr=df.collect()
print(dfr)
```

This is my attempt at trying to implement the INSERT INTO / the dataframe method. I'm still getting the same AnalysisException error.

```
%pyspark
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

sql = sqlContext.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE kenny_target(`user`, `age`) SELECT `user`, COALESCE(`age`, 0L) FROM kenny_source")
frame= sqlContext.createDataFrame(sql).collect()
frame.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("kenny_source_test")

test = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM test_source_test")
dfr=test.collect()
print(dfr)
```

Comment: I forgot to add that this was in Zeppelin notebook. The ` ` is the correct syntax. I'll make a note of that now.

Comment: frame.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("kenny_source_test") should be df.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("kenny_source_test"), right?

Comment: You cannot do INSERT INTO. You should create a DataFrame (not use) and then append it.

Comment: Could you provide a code example of what you're referring to?

Comment: Added some lines. Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided the following code.

```
%pyspark
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

sql = sqlContext.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE kenny_target(`user`, `age`) SELECT 
`user`, COALESCE(`age`, 0L) FROM kenny_source")
frame= sqlContext.createDataFrame(sql).collect()
frame.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("kenny_source_test")
```

## You cannot do this for some reasons.

## 1. You are trying to create  a DataFrame again.

Assume, **INSERT INTO TABLE** is supported. When, you do **sqlContext.sql** (It
    will create a DataFrame).

```
sql = sqlContext.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE kenny_target('user', 'age') SELECT 'user', COALESCE('age', 0L) FROM kenny_source")
```

Next is this line. When you run this, spark will throw an error.

```
frame = sqlContext.createDataframe(sql)
```

> TypeError: data is already a DataFrame

## 2. You are trying to collect() a DataFrame and write it to the table.

You have this line of code.

```
# Since, you wrote sql = sqlContext.sql('query')
# You could write frame = sql.collect()
frame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sql).collect()
```

> Note, after you collect a
>       DataFrame (frame in this case), it is no longer a DataFrame. A
>       collect() always collects the DataFrame as List.

And the last line does not work because **frame** is a list (as you did collect() on it).

```
frame.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("kenny_source_test")
```

It throws an error stating

> 'list' object has no attribute 'write' # Reason: frame is now a list

**Resolution:**

```
# SELECT user and age into 'frame' by creating a DataFrame called as 'frame'
frame = sqlContext.sql('''SELECT `user`, COALESCE(`age`, 0L) FROM kenny_source''')

# Write it to the table: kenny_source_test
frame.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("kenny_source_test")
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. Was struggling to find a fix online.

Comment: Edited the answer. I hope this answer will give you an idea.